# moz-border-color in other browsers

Tags: css, colors, border

How can i use this

```
border-left:solid 11px;
border-right:solid 11px;
-moz-border-left-colors:#f0efe1 #efeee0 #eeeddf #edecdd #ecebdc #ebeadb #eae9da #e9e8d8 #e8e7d7 #e7e6d6 #e5e4d4;
-moz-border-right-colors:#f0efe1 #efeee0 #eeeddf #edecdd #ecebdc #ebeadb #eae9da #e9e8d8 #e8e7d7 #e7e6d6 #e5e4d4;
```

in other browsers?
I try to delete -moz prefix but i doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't appear to do anything at all in Firefox 8/Ubuntu 11.04. In which version of Firefox is this supposed to work?

Comment: i use the aurora version!!
it works also in firefox 8 (release version)

Comment: http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Mozilla docs for the `-moz-border-top-colors` property it specifically states:

> Supported since Gecko 1.0 (Firefox 1.0), no support in other major browsers.

Therefore there is no, currently-known (to me, at least), way of implementing this in other browsers, except for the nesting of elements to form each 'line' of the border.

References:

- [`-moz-border-top-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-top-colors).

Comment: The example in your link works for me in Firefox 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not intending to suggest that it doesn't work at all, just that in my test it didn't work for me in Firefox 8/Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: so designers wait w3.org addopt a standar for this use, and browsers include code for this..
Just wait guys..

Comment: Personally I hope this never makes it to specification. The syntax is horrible, especially for specifying gradient borders.